# ¿Cómo realizar un formato hexadecimal a 4 posiciones?

Tags: java, string, formato, compilador, números-enteros

Se que mi pregunta puede sonar un poco extraña, pero realmente es más fácil de entender de lo que parece.
Estoy realizando un compilador de instrucciones electrónicas, lo típico, encender un led, configurar puertos, etc.
Me estoy basando mucho en el código hexadecimal que genera **Proton IDE**

Cuando convierto una de las instrucciones a código hexadecimal, obtengo algo como por ejemplo un "2", pero quisiera pasarlo al siguiente formato hexadecimal:

```
'2' => '0200'
```

Otro ejempolo

```
'10' => 'A000'
```

*Tener muy en cuenta que estoy transformando un número decimal a un hexadecimal*

Para esta conversión estoy utilizando el siguiente método que proporciona Java

```
Integer.toHexString(numero);
```

¿Alguna idea de como obtener este formato de 4 posiciones?, o realmente, ¿Qué significa este formato? o ¿Está mal colocar este formato?

Comment: ya intentaste con `System.out.printf` y `String.format`?

Comment: 2 en hexadecimal es 2, o `0002`. Y 10 sería A o  `000A`